# mediaelement.js & Dropbox video link

Tags: dropbox, mediaelement.js

I was looking for a plugin that could play both audio and video files and was happy to come across mediaelement.js. I host all of my audio and video from Dropbox. The audio is playing fine but the video does not, just hangs on the loading screen.

I saw another thread posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15921968/how-mediaelement-js-uses-dropbox-link) with no response. Below is the shortcode I'm using:

```
[video src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/udprb5o5p3n6uu8/WCN.mp4" width="242" height="136" poster="http://wellsmartsolutions.com/video/video.png"]
```

Not other plugins are active that would be causing any conflict. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this URL instead: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/udprb5o5p3n6uu8/WCN.mp4. I've changed the domain to `dl.dropboxusercontent.com` per https://www.dropbox.com/help/201. This links directly to the video rather than a web page that previews the video.